Jmeter Throughput shaping timer different from desired throughput
I am using jmeter version 5.6.3 (latest).
So i have a jmeter test plan created as below, my goal is to run the test plan with a desired consistent 120 RPS.

The sampler is just a dummy sampler with random response time between 1000ms-1800ms,

My thread group is concurrency thread group and i have configured throughput shaping timer.


However, the overall throughput after running the test for 10 mins is 230.5 which is way higher than the desired 120, and why is that??


I cannot reproduce your issue, but you can try asking in JMeter Plugins Support Forum
The only thing I could suggest taking a look at jmeter.log file and look for lines with VariableThroughputTimer, they will be related to the Throughput Shaping Timer.
It might also be a good idea to enable JMeter debug logging for the Throughput Shaping Timer, add the next line to log4j2.xml file:
<Logger name="kg.apc.jmeter.timers" level="debug" />

and restart JMeter, you will see what's going on in the jmeter.log file and possibly you will be able to figure out where the problem is.
